# opening Mobile-Angular-ui modal dialog from controller

Tags: angularjs

I am using mobile-angular-ui for mobile devices. But i am facing issues with opening the dialog from controller.

### controller

```
$scope.openModal = function() {
            SharedState.initialize($scope, 'modal1');
               // SharedState.turnOn('modal1');
            $rootScope.Ui.turnOn('modal1');
            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: '../scripts/app/account/modal-dialog/modal.html',
                controller: 'SearchController', //This must be a referance, not a string
                size: 'sm'
            });
        }
```

### View

```
<a href ui-turn-on="modal1" ng-click="openModal()">link</a>
```

But i am getting empty modal content.

Answer (score 0):

Try $rootScope.Ui.turnOn('modal1') instead of SharedState.turnOn('modal1');

[github-mobile-angular-ui/issues/252](https://github.com/mcasimir/mobile-angular-ui/issues/252)